# Bash is not recognized?

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to build the [open source drivers](http://opensource.actiontec.com/c1000x.html) for the c1000a to fix my router. However, I run into a weird issue:

```
$ make PROFILE=963268BGW
make version is 3.81
kernel version is 3.13.0-29-generic
shell is /bin/sh.  Bash version is 
***************************************************
ERROR: /bin/sh does not invoke bash shell
***************************************************
make: *** [prebuild_checks] Error 1
```

Can anyone explain what this might mean?

Comment: Assuming this is linux, that does seem strange.

Comment: On many linux systems, `/bin/sh` is a link to `dash` or some other light-weight shell.  Your source code appears to require that `/bin/sh` instead be linked to `/bin/bash`.  You can (a) temporarily change where `/bin/sh` points (this could have unexpected side-effects) or (b) find whereever your source code has `/bin/sh` and change it to `/bin/bash`.  To attempt (a), as root, do (1) `mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.save; ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`, (2) compile your code, and (3) `mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.bash; mv /bin/sh.save /bin/sh`.  To start on (b), try running `grep -r /bin/sh` and report back on the results.

Comment: Or find that, hopefully, the build process allows you to specify the shell to use (possibly even through the SHELL make variable) and use that to specify bash. Then file a ticket/issue/etc. with the providers of the drivers and tell them that if they want bash they should try to run bash and not /bin/sh because that is stupid.

Comment: I found the condition in the makefile and manually edited it. Thus far I have managed to build it but it still needs tuning to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that someone wrote a script or Makefile which depends on `/bin/sh` being Bash, and went out of their way to write code to detect that this is the case, rather than to write code which finds the shell that is required to run the script, like `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash`.

It is easy to tell GNU Make what shell to use for executing build "recipes" (bodies of rules), namely the `SHELL` variable. The default is `/bin/sh/` but if you put

```
SHELL = /usr/bin/bash  # or whatever else
```

then GNU Make will use that.

I'd gut the Makefile of the logic which tests `/bin/sh` and bails out, and set up the `SHELL` variable to point to Bash.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be an error in the make.common file. I ended up modifying it to fix the issue. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

This error might happen when you are doing compilation in Debian flavor distributions such as Ubuntu. Use the command below to compile:

```
$> make PROFILE=963268BGW SHELL=/bin/bash
```